# error message for values not found using Find function

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this code to check if a barcode is on the database but every time the barcode is not on the list it prompts  an error message saying:

> Runtime Error 91 : Object variable or With block variable not set.

Is there a line I can add like a msgbox that the barcode entered is invalid. I understand that this is what I need but apparently, I don't know which function I should use to come with an IF statement. Any suggestions?

I would also appreciate if anyone can suggest using the FOR statement if a batch would be searched say nos. 1111-1114

```
Private Sub CheckBarcodeStatusCommandButton_Click()
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory Log").Select
    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Find(What:=CheckBarcodeTextBox.Text, after:=ActiveCell, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, MatchByte:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "In" Then
        MsgBox ("The barcode no. " & CheckBarcodeTextBox.Text _
            & " is currently available")
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Out" Then
        MsgBox ("The barcode no. " & CheckBarcodeTextBox.Text _
            & " has already been used.")
    End If

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52268120/8112776) below.  Unrelated to your issue, note that if `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` were needed (which it's not in this case), it would go at the *beginning* of the procedure, with `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` at the *end*.  A harmless mistake in this case, but there are similar functions which can have more impact, even affecting other applications when used incorrectly. (ie. `SetWarnings`)  It's a good idea to consult the documentation on any functions/methods that you're unfamiliar with.  (See links below my answer.)

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.range.find):

> This method returns `Nothing` if no match is found. The `.Find` method does not affect the selection or the active cell.

---

**This demonstrates how to use the VBA `.Find` method:**

This assumes (based on your example) that `CheckBarcodeTextBox` contains text to match in Column `J`, matching the "entire cell" only.

```
Private Sub CheckBarcodeStatusCommandButton_Click()
    Dim lookFor As String, lookIn As Range, found As Range

    lookFor = CheckBarcodeTextBox.Text
    Set lookIn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory Log").Columns("J:J")
    Set found = lookIn.Find(lookFor, , xlValues, xlWhole) 'match whole cell value

    If found Is Nothing Then
        'not found
        MsgBox "No match for: " & lookFor
    Else
        'found
        MsgBox "Found: " & lookFor & vbLf & _
               " in cell: " & found.Address & vbLf & _
               " which contains: " & found.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

If you only need to check if a match *exists* (and don't need to know the *location* of the match), then the above example can be simplified a bit.

```
Private Sub CheckBarcodeStatusCommandButton_Click()
    Dim lookIn As Range
    Set lookIn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory Log").Columns("J")
    If lookIn.Find(CheckBarcodeTextBox, , xlValues, xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Not found:."    'do something if not found
    Else
        MsgBox "Found."         'do something if found
    End If
End Sub
```

In a worksheet formula I'd use `VLOOKUP` or `MATCH`, which can be called using `Application.WorksheetFunction` but both requires `On Error` handling to deal with non-matches, so `.Find` is probably best.

---

### More Information from Microsoft Docs:

- [**`Range.Find` Method** (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)
- [**`Application.DisplayAlerts` Property** (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayalerts)

[image] *Recommended Bookmark*: **Microsoft Documentation: [Office VBA Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba)**
<sup>Use the sites' left sidebar to navigate to sections like VBA [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/functions-visual-basic-for-applications), [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/methods-visual-basic-for-applications) and [statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/statements).</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try this also.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Private Sub CheckBarcodeStatusCommandButton_Click()
    dim c as range

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory Log").Columns("J:J").Select
    on error resume next
    set c = Selection.Find(What:=CheckBarcodeTextBox.Text, after:=ActiveCell, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, MatchByte:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False)

    if c is nothing then 
        msgbox "barcode not found."
    else
        c.Activate

        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "In" Then
            MsgBox ("The barcode no. " & CheckBarcodeTextBox.Text _
                & " is currently available")
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Out" Then
            MsgBox ("The barcode no. " & CheckBarcodeTextBox.Text _
                & " has already been used.")
        End If
    end if
    on error goto 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try this. In the past I used similar code but it shows error with the word Nothing..  =( but i will try this must be a correct code.

Answer (score 1):

The worksheet's MATCH is as fast or faster than Range.Find within a single column. Using Application.Match returned to a variant allows you to test with IsError.

```
Private Sub CheckBarcodeStatusCommandButton_Click()
    dim m as variant, str as string

    with ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory Log")

        str = CheckBarcodeTextBox.Text
        m = application.match(str, .range("J:J"), 0)

        if not iserror(m) then
            If .cells(m, "K").Value = "In" Then
                MsgBox ("The barcode no. " & str & " is currently available")
            ElseIf .cells(m, "K").Value = "Out" Then
                MsgBox ("The barcode no. " & str & " has already been used.")
            End If
        else
            'maybe do something if not found
        end if

    end with

End Sub
```