# Handling #NA Value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, match, lookup, worksheet

I have written VBA code which **copies data from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2`** with the help of the `Match` function based on the column value.

The `Match` function is throwing error as some value are not available in the `Sheet2` Column, so for that I try to use the following code:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

The code copied the data from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` but when the code doesn't find the `Match`, it inserted the same value of the last column into the next column also.

So I tried using the following code to handle `#NA` error:

`cont = Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet2.Cells(1, i), Sheet1.Range("A3:Ah3"), 0))`

But code itself started throwing error, and when I try using both the code together, the cont variables value is always false.

The full code of the problem is as follow:

```
Sub Copy()
Dim lastColumnSheet2 As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim temp As Long
Dim cont As Boolean


lastColumnSheet2 = Sheet2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

On Error Resume Next
For i = 2 To lastColumnSheet2
    'cont = Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet2.Cells(1, i), Sheet1.Range("A3:Ah3"), 0))
    'If cont = False Then
    temp = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet2.Cells(1, i), Sheet1.Range("A1:Ah1"), 0)


        If Sheet2.Cells(2, i).Value = "" Then
                Sheet2.Cells(2, i).Value = Sheet1.Cells(2, temp).Value

        End If
    'Else
    'End If

Next i
```

Can anyone please guide me how to handle a `#NA` error in VBA?

This is the link to sample data with code : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-luUAqleKgxcg4pWl_Mn4ecI9HrjnJAq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` should generally be avoided.  It is not for *handling* errors, it is for *ignoring* errors.  Here's an overview of [VBA Error Handling](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) from Chip Pearson.

Comment: Provide enough code and sample of data that we can reproduce this in a meaningful way for you.

Comment: This is the link to the sample data with code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-luUAqleKgxcg4pWl_Mn4ecI9HrjnJAq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Karan - it's best to have all related information within your question. You can [edit] your post to add the relevant code and sample data.  (See **how to create a [mcve]** as well as "[ask]" and this [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).)

Comment: @Karan ...actually, my [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52268120/8112776) to another question a few hours ago shows an alternate solution using `.Find` (and mentions why it's better than `Match` or `VLookUp` in VBA.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the rest of your code but just to show how you can handle that error being returned potentially by the `Match` function. Declare `temp` as a variant so it can store an error value if returned. Use `Application.Match` which can return error values without throwing a hissy fit. Test `temp` for whether it is an error with `IsError` and then act accordingly.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CopyInfo()
    Dim lastColumnSheet2 As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim temp As Variant
    Dim cont As Boolean

    lastColumnSheet2 = Sheet2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 2 To lastColumnSheet2

        temp = Application.Match(Sheet2.Cells(1, i), Sheet1.Range("A1:AH1"), 0)

        If Not IsError(temp) And IsEmpty(Sheet2.Cells(2, i)) Then
            Sheet2.Cells(2, i).Value = Sheet1.Cells(2, temp).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: When you run the VBA file, the file starts giving error on the line where temp value is being assigned, the code don't even go to the if statement

Comment: What is the error please and did you declare temp as variant?

Comment: Temp is declared as Double and the error which I am getting is "Run time error '1004' Unable to get the Match propertyof the WorksheetFunction class"

Comment: Please use the code as per my example.  See the line where I say... _Declare temp as a variant so it can store an error value if returned_

Comment: Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Still the same error after declaring temp as variant

Comment: I had typed excel.workbookfunction.Match. Now after changing the code it passes that line but still I am getting error inside if statement, while assigning the value.
The error I am getting is "Run type error 13. Type Mismatch"

Comment: That doesn't exist. Also, please look carefully at my answer. It uses Application.Match and the reason _Use Application.Match which can return error values without throwing a hissy fit_

Comment: There was some mistake, after rectifying that the code work without errors, but it doesn't print anything

Comment: my code works as I tested it. You need to step through your code with F8 line by line and examine the values of the variables and work out where the you get an unexpected result of the code doesn't branch as you would expect it to.

Comment: At presently I am working on something else, When I will work on this code I will let you know. Thanks